# What is the exact meaning of 'shout over' in a sentence?

Tags: verbs

I'm a Persian who is reading the novel, *The Talented Mr Ripley*. I have come across the following sentence:

> The Italian had a long, gray car with a loud radio that he and Dickie seemed happy to shout over.

I do not know the meaning of the phrase "shout over". Can someone please explain what is meant by this sentence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**To shout over something** means to shout more loudly than something.  They simplest sentence for that meaning would be "They shouted over the radio", which means that the two people had to shout to be louder than the sound of the radio.

In your context that means the radio is loud, they have to shout to hear each other, and they enjoy all the noise.

The context tells us they are not communicating by the radio.  An alternative context might be: "The policemen had to shout over the radio for help."  In this case, they are shouting *by means of* the radio.

Comment: Note that "shout over" is not an idiom or established phrase. It's just the verb "shout" plus the preposition "over" meaning (of sounds) "more prominent than", or "obscuring".